# GitHub API v3 get all issues for user

Tags: github, github-api

I am currently developing a project using githubs v3 api and I am trying to find a way to get all issues across all repositories a user owns and is watching. How can I do that? The /user/issues and /issues only returns issues that a person is assigned to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The endpoint you are using is correct:

`/api.github.com/user/issues`

According to the [GitHub API page on issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues), you can get all issues a user is subscribed to by including the `filter` parameter set to `subscribed` with your request.

You can get all issues a user is subscribed to at

`/api.github.com/user/issues?filter=subscribed`

Comment: This seems to limited to returning repos the authenticated user either owns or is a member of?